# consultation ,Calculating Weight Adjustments for hidden-Layer Neurons

Tags: neural-network

In the calculations for the given network, I understood the Forward-Pass Calculation calculations, but in the Backward-Pass Calculation section; When calculating Calculating Weight Adjustments for Hidden-Layer Neurons W1-11, the E/H1 value = d(E/O1) * d(O1/Z11) ), I could not understand the calculation part. I hope I was able to explain my problem.

In the first picture, I understood the calculation for w211, but in the second picture, in the calculation for w111; why  $\frac{dE}{dH1} = \frac{dE}{dO1} * \frac{dO1}{dZ_{1}^{2}} $ was calculated with the same values of -0.18980111 and 0.237856214 as in the first calculation, $\frac{dE}{dH1} $ calculation.

The network architecture is as follows:

[image]

First Picture:
[image]
Second Picture:
[image]